# PowerShell, doesn't contain method 'items'

Tags: windows, string, file, powershell, io

When executing this code, I received the error below:

```
$filesExist = Test-Path($file)
if ($filesExist) {
    $shell_app=new-object -com shell.application
    $zip_file = Get-Item "$mindCrackFolder\files.zip"
    $destination = Get-Item $mindCrackFolder

    $destination.Copyhere($zip_file.items(), 0x14)
    #Remove-Item "$zip_file"
    #Remove-Item "install.ps1"
}
```

Error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'items'.
At C:\Users\User1\Desktop\ps install\install.ps1:33 char:5
+     $destination.Copyhere($zip_file.items(), 0x14)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

But I already convertered $destination into a IO object to be manipulated?  Can I get any help, this my first time experimenting with PS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing do with $destination.  `$zip_file.items()` is evaluated first and the error message is telling you that the .NET System.IO.FileInfo object returned by `Get-Item` has no `Items()` method.  `Get-Item` only returns an object that provides information about a file - size, last write time, readonly or not, etc.  You can't use Get-Item to access the contents of a ZIP file.

If you need to extract the contents of the ZIP file, consider using the [PowerShell Community Exensions'](http://pscx.codeplex.com) `Expand-Archive` cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

The errors is talking about the object you use the `items()` method on = `$zip_file`. Powershell doesn't have built-in zip support, you gotta create it(using shell.application com-object, google it) or add a .net library. `$zip_file` is just a simple FileInfo object just as the ones you get from `dir`(Get-ChildItem). It does not contain an `items()` method.

Solution: as previously said, google `powershell zip files` to read about how you can use zip files in powershell. My suggestion is [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PS-Examples)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what and where you learned these, but you seem to have copied some code wrongly and made changes ad-hoc. Try the below script which does what you want:

```
$shell_app=new-object -com shell.application
$filename = "test.zip"
$zip_file = $shell_app.namespace((Get-Location).Path + "\$filename")
$destination = $shell_app.namespace((Get-Location).Path)
$destination.Copyhere($zip_file.items(), 0x14)
```

The `items` and `copyHere` method are not available on `FileInfo` objects, which is what you get from `Get-Item`. Use them as shown above.